# Moving a MAC font to a PC - How?

Tags: macos, fonts

This has been a rather problematic issue on numerous occasions.  We have alot of our designers using Macs for design and the fonts based on there but when we need to see designs on a PC the fonts are not there.

I was wondering if anyone knows a rather efficient and painless method of moving/copying a font from MAC OS X to PC (Windows).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what puprose are you doing this? Document templates? Web design? Other?

Comment: Web design using illustrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to pay, this seems like a solution:

[CrossFont](http://www.asy.com/)

If free is better, I'd try this:

[FontClerk](http://www.tucows.com/preview/204310)

Comment: FontClerk is unfortunatly too old (Date Added: December 31, 1996) OS X doesn't seem to support "Classic" mode any more.  

Don't really want to pay for something at the moment :/

Comment: Cross font seems to be the best i've seen so far. So that's the one we're now using. Cheers!